# Setting react state with nested objects from JSON fetch call

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am fetching recipes from a recipe app and id like to insert certain objects from the returning json result onto my state with setstate. I know how to do one of these but im having trouble figuring out how to map the results on to my state. Can anyone help me on this?

The code for the issue is here. I have changed my api key and code for security

```
componentDidMount() {
        let url = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=banana&app_id=chjhvje1&app_key=b67djhhvhvhaef`;
        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                let recipeUIState = [ ...this.state.RecipeUI ];
                recipeUIState[0].title = data.hits[0].recipe.label;
                recipeUIState[0].thumbnail = data.hits[0].recipe.image;
                recipeUIState[0].href = data.hits[0].recipe.url;

                this.setState({ RecipeUI: recipeUIState });

                console.log(data.hits[0].recipe);
            });
    }
```

State is as follows-

```
export default class RecipeUI extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            food: '',
            RecipeUI: [ { title: '' } ]
            // thumbnail: '', ingredients: '', href: ''
        };
        this.search = this.search.bind(this);
    }
```

reponse from API is attached as image[image: json response]

Comment: can you add your api response here? It will help in giving you correct help

Comment: What is the exact problem? How does your current code fail? And why do you have an array with a single element?

Comment: @ChrisG I want to select specific element (label, img, url)of each object that returns to me from the API and insert them into state. This should happen several times as each API call fetches 10 objects for a search query such as banana

Answer (score 0):

```
data.hits.forEach(({ recipe }) => {
  // We get the original state every before it's updated in the iteration
  const recipeUIState = [...this.state.RecipeUI];
  // Check if there's an existing recipe with the same title
  const idx = recipeUIState.findIndex(r => r.title === recipe.title);

  // Helper object to create a recipe from the current iteration
  const currentRecipe = {
    title: recipe.label,
    thumbnail: recipe.image,
    href: recipe.url
  };

  // `findIndex` returns -1 if no entry was found, otherwise it returns the index
  if (idx < 0) {
    // No existing recipe was found, append the new recipe to the original state
    return this.setState({
      recipeUIState: [...recipeUIState, ...currentRecipe]
    });
  }

  // Recipe already existed, create a new recipe by overwriting
  // the object at the index we found earlier
  const newRecipeUIState = {
    ...recipeUIState[idx],
    ...currentRecipe
  };

  // Replace the recipe at found index
  recipeUIState[idx] = newRecipeUIState;

  this.setState({ recipeUIState });
});
```

Something like this? could probably be simplified using `Array#reduce` but I don't feel too comfortable using it.

Comment: Thanks mate, im having some trouble understanding this, can you help me with it?

Comment: Sure, which part do you not understand?

Comment: what role does const idx = recipeUIState.findIndex(r => r.title === recipe.title); play?

Comment: It's used to attempt to find a existing recipe with the same title to decide if we need to replace the recipe at the index that could be returned [See the docs on findIndex here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Comment: hmm, im not sure whether this fits what I'm looking to do mate.  What I want is to do is scan all the data that is returned to me in each object for the label, image and url and insert these into an object. this object will then be pushed into my state via setState. this must hapen several times as when i search for something like banana,10 objects come back to me

Comment: I have added some comments so you can omit the parts that you do not need, however I would consider replacing (updating) existing objects (that's what this code does in addition to what you just mentioned) because what if you search for the same thing twice and the label or image was updated?

Comment: I made some progress here mate. I succeded in getting several objects that have the elements i want . I am however having some issue with pushing them into state with setstate as i get a TypeError: this.state.RecipeUI.map is not a function. Could you assist? :) The code is here- https://www.codepile.net/pile/xErY1RWy

Comment: I am not familair with class components, I suggest you create a new question since it's out of the scope of this one